# this.state vs state in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, react-props

I'm working in a new codebase. Normally, I would set up state like this in a React component:

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state={
            foo: 'bar'
        }
     }
    ....
```

In this new codebase, I'm seeing a lot of this:

```
class App extends React.Component {
    state={
        foo: 'bar'
     }
    ....
```

Is there an advantage to doing it this way? They seem to only do it when state doesn't need to be altered. I always thought of state as being something React handled. Is this an ok thing to do?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The end result of both approaches is the same. Both approaches are just setting the initial `state` of the component. It's worth noting that [class properties are a stage 3 proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields), so all development environments may not be able to use them.

I personally like to use the class field variant if nothing else is done in the constructor, as it is less code to write, and you have no `super` call to worry about.

**Example**

```
class Component1 extends React.Component {
  state = { value: this.props.initialValue };

  render() {
    return <div> {this.state.value} </div>
  }
}

class Component2 extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { value: props.initialValue };
  }

  render() {
    return <div> {this.state.value} </div>
  }
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Component1 initialValue={1} />
      <Component2 initialValue={2} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Actually both of them bind to `this` pointer. the `this` that made in `constructor` of `class`.

Totally you can access to local state by `this.state` but in first style you can pass `props` to `constructor` by `super` and then use it in `state` declaration, just like below:

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state={
            foo: 'bar',
            jaz: props.someParentState,
        }
     }
....
```

Awesome, you can access to `props` in `constructor`, isn't pretty? I definitely use this style for local state declaration.

Hope this helps you.