# How to make React.js fetch data from api as state and pass this state data from its parent to child component

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, fetch

I am working on a React.js + D3.js project. I wanted App.js to fetch data from a json file and save this data into state and pass this parent sate data down to my child component state through the property. I found if I use static data in App.js works fine, but once fetching from a json file, it failed because no data can be stored into property. My App.js like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import SandkeyGraph from './particle/SandkeyGraph';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    data : null
  }

  // works fine in this way!
  // state = {
  //   data: {
  //     "nodes":[
  //     {"node":0,"name":"node0"},
  //     {"node":1,"name":"node1"},
  //     {"node":2,"name":"node2"},
  //     {"node":3,"name":"node3"},
  //     {"node":4,"name":"node4"}
  //     ],
  //     "links":[
  //     {"source":0,"target":2,"value":2},
  //     {"source":1,"target":2,"value":2},
  //     {"source":1,"target":3,"value":2},
  //     {"source":0,"target":4,"value":2},
  //     {"source":2,"target":3,"value":2},
  //     {"source":2,"target":4,"value":2},
  //     {"source":3,"target":4,"value":4}
  //     ]}
  // }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.getData('./data/sankey.json');
  }

  getData = (uri) => {
    fetch(uri)
    .then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
      // successful got the data
      console.log(data);
      this.setState({ data });
   });
  }

  render() {
    // failed
    const { data } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <SandkeyGraph
          height={300}
          width={700}
          id="d3-sankey" 
          sankeyData = {this.state.data} 
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

parrt of my  is like this:

```
class SankeyGraph extends Component {
  displayName: 'SankeyGraph';

  state = {
    sankeyData : null
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state.sankeyData = props.sankeyData || null;
  }

  PropTypes : {
    id : PropTypes.string,
    height: PropTypes.number,
    width: PropTypes.number,
    sankeyData : PropTypes.object,
  }

  componentDidMount () {
     // will be null, if using fetch from App.js
    //console.log(this.state.sankeyData);
    this.setContext();
  }
 //...
```

Does anyone know how to handle this situation? Thank you so much in advanced!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After working out the problem, it turned out that there was no problem with `fetch`. It just didn't account for `null` in any of the components in the program (It would crash after using a `null` value.

For example in render:

```
render() {
    if (this.state.data) {
      return (
        <div>
          <SandkeyGraph
            height={300}
            width={700}
            id="d3-sankey" 
            sankeyData = {this.state.data} 
          />
        </div>
      );
    }
    else {
      return <div/>
    }
}
```

Or, the use of a ternary operator would work as well to be more concise (answer by @Eliran):

```
return (
  {this.state.data ?
    <div>
      <SandkeyGraph
        height={300}
        width={700}
        id="d3-sankey" 
        sankeyData = {this.state.data} 
      />
    </div> : <div>No Data Available</div>
);
```

Comment: Hi Kevin, Thank you so much! After I updated this.setState, the data still not able to pass down. but I think it's pretty close. In render(), IDE gives me a hint that:  'data' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars , do you think there are some thing wrong with it?

Comment: It's just a warning so it won't affect anything, but that's still weird (you are using the data variable). Which line is it giving you the warning?

Comment: It's this line:  const { data } = this.state;  in render() function

Comment: So the reason why you're getting the warning is because you're not using the `data` variable. But, I misread your first comment and didn't realize that you're still not able push the JSON data to your component. If you `console.log(data)` in the render function, what do you get as an output?

Comment: Hi Kevin, thank you so much for response. If I console.log(data) I got null and if I console.log(this.data) I got {data : null}

Comment: Is the `console.log()` after data is defined? or else you need to `console.log(this.state.data)`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185333/discussion-between-kevin-bai-and-zichen-ma).

Comment: After @Kevin Bai 's solution:  just added one line: if (data == null) { 
return null; 
} in App render() function, it works

Answer (score 1):

You can add in your render function a condition:

```
render() {
// failed
const { data } = this.state;
return (
  <div>
    {data ?
    <SandkeyGraph
      height={300}
      width={700}
      id="d3-sankey" 
      sankeyData={data} 
    /> : "Loading..."
    }
  </div>
);
}
```

and only if data is populated the component will be rendered.

Comment: Hi Eliran, that's a good idea. Definitely, will use it! However, my problem is the data from App.js using fetch cannot pass down to my child component: <SandkeyGraph>, I think there might be something wrong with my this.setState?

Comment: Hi Eliran, I just realized your way is correct. In that moment, I couldn't know it's an aysc issue. After I added if statement, it works fine

Answer (score 0):

```
...
class App extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props)

  this.state = {
    data : null
  }
}
```

It seems like an error on the state declaration?

Comment: Hi Fidelio, I might wrong, but if I change to static state data (I commented out, that part) everything works fine.

Comment: This could help with state declarations, it seems like in this way you can pass props to constructor and use with your state: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51118103/this-state-vs-state-in-react

Comment: Hi Fidelio, I checked it. Seems both ways should work fine. using this.sate and state={}

Answer (score 0):

1.- Import your json in App component on top like this: import jsonData from './data/sankey.json'

2.- Set jsonData in state jsonData in App component.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
    jsonData : {}
  }
}

componentWillMount() {
     this.setState({ jsonData })
  }
```

You do not need to fetch as you have your json locally.

Once you have your json in your state, you can display it in render like this for example:

```
this.state.jsonData.data.links.map(x=>
  <div>
   <div>x.links.source</div>
   <div>x.links.target</div>
  </div>
)
```

Comment: Hi Niels,  I tried your way, seems not working. I open the chrome development tool ,try to find sanky.json, but couldn't find this file when App loaded

Comment: Hi, I am sure 100% it works if you use create-react-app (it integrates the module https://github.com/webpack-contrib/json-loader). You can post your folder structure + your code and will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I've been testing and you need to replace the getData() method to this:

```
  getData = (uri) => {
    fetch(uri, {
      headers : { 
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
       }
    })
    .then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
      // successful got the data
      console.log(data);
      this.setState({ data });
   });
  }
```

This is because you need to declare 'Content-Type' and 'Accept' headers on your fetch options in order to make your request.

Comment: Hi Fidelo, still the same, I can get the data from in App.js but cannot pass it into <SandkeyGraph>

Comment: The error output is : TypeError: Cannot read property ' notes' of null. This error is from the child component : sankey
      .nodes(graph.nodes)  which I defined : const graph = this.state.sankeyData; I think because data couldn't pass down to child component, the graph is null. I am wondering if I can give you my code in some way, so maybe is easier to take look at this issue. but anyway, so appreciated your time!

Comment: I tried in a new and clean component, props are available. Please, check your syntax.

Comment: Hi Fidelio, so appreciated your time. Yeah, I checked my code, it's fine. Just a asynchronize issue. finally I added this line of code: if (data == null) { return null; } in App render() function, it works