# What is the diffrence between the following ways of initalizing the state

Tags: reactjs, react-native

all just want to know the difference b/w the following ways to initialize the state and is there any advantage or disadvantage over using another one, or both are just syntactic sugar.

i)

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { bar: 0 }
  }
  render() {
    return <div>Foo</div>
  }
}
```

ii)

```
class Foo extends React.Component {  
  state = { bar: 0 }

  render() {
    return <div>Foo</div>
  }
}
```

Did anyone have any idea and what method i should prefer in which situation

Comment: I believe your second example is not complete

Comment: In the first example you can initialize the state using props, while on the second you can't.

Comment: @MorKadosh No, the second example is a complete class component. Very minimal, but complete and valid.

Comment: @DrewReese OP didn't format properly. So few lines were hidden.

Comment: @RameshReddy Ah, I see, then I probably would have just left it at that with the comment instead of also editing in syntactically correct and complete code. You never know if they have a typo in their code.

Comment: @MorKadosh are you sure about that? I'm pretty sure `this.props` will work in the second case as well. Although it has been a while since I've used or even seen a class components, so do correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [this.state vs state in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51118103/this-state-vs-state-in-react)